# Embedding unity 2018 project into Xcode9.4.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unity-game-engine, vuforia

everyone.
Currently, our team is developing AR function on Unity 2018, and I'm using swift 4 in Xcode 9.4.1. I do not understand anything about unity or c#, however, I need to finish embedding unity in our existing swift project. 
I tried methods from blizagency, jiulongw and www.the-nerd.be who have helped a lot people, but I realized Xcode and unity have been updated several times and I cannot successfully embed unity in iOS with those methods. Maybe I did something wrong, but I really need help here. Is there anyone able to help me out? Thank you!

Xcode version: 9.4.1

Unity version: 2018.2.0f2

other: Vuforia is used in unity project

Trials:

1)Method from www.the-nerd.be(video)

2)Method from blizagency(GitHub)

3)Method from jiulongw(GitHub)

Comment: Or maybe if there is someone recently finished embedding, I am very glad to hear your suggestions!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this tutorial. He is using Unity 2017 but it might still work.

https://dev-videos.com/videos/2PW7_CfIwY0/Embedding-Unity-Games-inside-iOS-Apps